# How can I make multiple nested http request in RxJs?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, fetch, httprequest

I'm newbie to RxJs. I could not find how to do it. I have a large number of nested http requests in my master data. And I want to get all the http requests and combine them all in my main stream.

My example main stream data as:

```
[
    {
        id: '123',
        name: 'nameVal1',
        salary: [
            { href: 'http://example.com/salary/1' },
            { href: 'http://example.com/salary/2' }
        ],
        address: {
            href: 'http:/example.com/address'
        }
    },

    {
        id: '456',
        name: 'nameVal2',
        salary: {
            href: 'http://example.com/salary/1'
        },
        address: {
            href: 'http:/example.com/address'
        }
    }
];
```

Example salary object:

```
{
    salary: '1000€',
    month: 2
}
```

Example address object:

```
{
    country: 'UK',
    city: 'London',
    postalCode: '123'
}
```

My main stream is array of objects like above and after get the main stream, I want to get all nested data and combine them all the main stream like that:

```
[
{
    id: '123',
    name: 'nameVal1',
    salary: [
        {
            salary: '1000€',
            month: 2
        },
        {
            salary: '500€',
            month: 3
        }
    ],
    address: {
        country: 'UK',
        city: 'London',
        postalCode: '123'
    }
},

{
    id: '456',
    name: 'nameVal2',
    salary: [
        {
            salary: '2000€',
            month: 3
        }
    ],
    address: {
        country: 'UK',
        city: 'London',
        postalCode: '456'
    }
}
];


this.service.mainHttpReq().pipe(
    map(users => {
        users.salary.forEach(salaryItem => { 
            return fetch(salaryItem.href); 
        });
        

    })
).subscribe(usersData => {
   console.log('Users Data :', usersData);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `forkJoin` to fetch data in parallel.

```ts
mainStream.pipe(
  // fetch data for every person
  switchMap(persons => forkJoin(
    persons.map(person => getPersonData(person))
  ))
);

// get data for a single person
function getPersonData(person): Observable<any> {
  // the salary data as an observable
  const salaryData = forkJoin(person.salary.map(({ href }) => getSalaryData(href));
  // the address data as an observable
  const addressData = getAddressData(person.address.href);
  // combine salary and address data
  return forkJoin(salaryData, addressData).pipe(
    // map salary and address data to a person object with this data
    map(([ salary, address ]) => ({ ...person, salary, address }))
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The right solution might depend on whether you want to fetch salaries concurrently or not but you could do it for example like this:

```
this.service.mainHttpReq().pipe(
  concatAll(), // Unwrap the users array into individual `next` values representing each user.
  concatMap(user => // Process users in sequnece one by one.
    forkJoin( // Fetch all salaries and address for this user in parallel.
      forkJoin(user.salary.map(salary => fetch(salaryItem.href))), 
      fetch(user.address),
    ).pipe(
      map(([salaries, address]) => { // Update the original user object.
        user.salary = salaries; 
        user.address = address;
        return user;
      }),
    ),
  ),
  toArray(), // Collect into a one array of users.
).subscribe(...);
```

I didn't test the code above but I hove you'll get how it works.